# ssh_config -t option

Tags: ssh, openssh

Is there a way to add a host to ssh_config with a rule that emulates the -t option in the ssh command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who came across this old question like I did, now it works the following way:

> RequestTTY
>
> Specifies whether to request a pseudo-tty for the session.  The argument may be one of: no (never request a TTY), yes (always request a TTY when standard input is
>                a TTY), force (always request a TTY) or auto (request a TTY when opening a login session).  This option mirrors the -t and -T flags for ssh(1).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I searched the man pages and asked around a bit and it looks like your best option for doing this will be to define an alias for it or make a script. I also looked for some catch all command you can use in ssh_config to specify options that don't have config file equivalents and surprisingly, there isn't one.  I downloaded the latest version of openssh and it looks like there isn't even any option for it there.  So if its something you really need, I'd submit a bug/feature request over it because it really should be an option since nearly every other option has an config file command for it.